# Deploying an app to Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy an app to Google App Engine. I have followed [these steps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading).

However, I am not clear how to perform this step:

```
appcfg.py update guestbook/
```

When I run this command

```
c:/python27 >> appcfg.py update guestbook/
```

It will open appcfg.py file in editor. How to run this command?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows when you type `appcfg.py` in command line the file will be opened by associated application.

So, you need to execute your command as follows:

`<path-to-python-executable> appcfg.py update guestbook`

In my case, `<path-to-python-executable>` is `C:\Cygwin\bin\python2.7.exe`